# Select specific rows which has several attributes in another table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

TABLE: occupiedrooms

| name | branchNo | roomNo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 2 | 100 |
| cba | 1 | 100 |
| aaa | 2 | 101 |

TABLE: allrooms

| roomNo | branchNo |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 |
| 100 | 2 |
| 101 | 1 |
| 101 | 2 |

And i want to get all rooms that are NOT occupied. I'ved tried

```
select * from allrooms where allrooms.roomNo not in (select roomNo from occupiedrooms)
```

but then it turns out that it will disregard room 101 branch 1 because its room number exists in occupiedrooms.

How can I query these tables to get all non-occupied rooms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the tuple `allrooms.roomNo, allrooms.branchNo` (not ony `allrooms.roomNo`)

```
select * from allrooms 
where (allrooms.roomNo, allrooms.branchNo)  not in (select roomNo, branchNo  from occupiedrooms)
```